# The URL <filename> is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` to work with SharePoint 2013 files in asp.net MVC project. I am able to load file then execute the query but after loading, I have to checkout file. On checkout I am getting following error:

> The URL is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

I created this file via asp.net MVC project only. its fine while creating a file on Sharepoint via code. I also checked out that file from SharePoint directly. It's working fine there.

Note:- File which needs to be checkout is under subsite.

The following is my sample code:

```
 //siteUrl = xxx.com
 //subsite = acct
 //relUrl =  /acct/doclib/test.txt
using (ClientContext ctx = getContext(siteUrl))
    {
        var site = ctx.Web;
        var file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);
        try
        {
            ctx.Load(file)
            ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
            if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
            {
                file.CheckOut();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // this line is causing error
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: url is correct as i guess, its like https://xxx.sharepoint.com/acct/SA/PL Synopsis Repository/test.txt

Comment: relative url is only without xxx.sharepoint.com. i just gave you full url including site base url. realtive url is just /acct/SA/PL Synopsis Repository/47101-092016.xlsx it has spaces. is this could be reason of this?